# Split a string in Python with ) and space after

Tags: python, jython

I have a string like that :

```
'srv1(compA1 compA2) srv2(compA3 compA2) srv3(comp4 comp5)'
```

I need to split it like this :

```
['srv1(compA1 compA2)', 'srv2(compA3 compA2)', 'srv3(comp4 comp5)' ]
```

I tried to split it by space but it splits the inner string of comp1 comp2...

Comment: checkout [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [9]: import re

In [10]: string = 'srv1(compA1 compA2) srv2(compA3 compA2) srv3(comp4 comp5)'

In [11]: re.split(r'(?<=\)) ', string)
Out[11]: ['srv1(compA1 compA2)', 'srv2(compA3 compA2)', 'srv3(comp4 comp5)']
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can Try this way

```
a='srv1(compA1 compA2) srv2(compA3 compA2) srv3(comp4 comp5)'
print a.replace(' s','###s').split('###')

#output
['srv1(compA1 compA2)', 'srv2(compA3 compA2)', 'srv3(comp4 comp5)']
```

or you can use `regular expression`

Answer (score 0):

You could split on ') ' and then add the ')' back in like this:

```
line = 'srv1(compA1 compA2) srv2(compA3 compA2) srv3(comp4 comp5)'
[e if e.endswith(')') else e + ')' for e in line.split(') ')]
['srv1(compA1 compA2)', 'srv2(compA3 compA2)', 'srv3(comp4 comp5)']
```

It's a bit ugly but it works.